# I am getting a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I have to search a value in sheet2 in column c and display its contents on a user form.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub searchdata()
    Dim erow As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    lastrow = Sheets("Resolution").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    count = 0

    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If Sheets("Resolution").Cells(x, 1) = Sheet2.Range("$C2:$c92") Then
            Sheet2.Range("F25") = Sheets("Resolution").Cell(x, 1)
            Sheet2.Range("G25") = Sheets("Resolution").Cell(x, 2)
            Sheet2.Range("H25") = Sheets("Resolution").Cell(x, 3)
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next x
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: First of all you are declaring the variable `WS`and not using it, `Sheet2` isn't declared and you are not referencing which workbooks is in `Sheets("Resolution")`. You need to sort all this out.

Comment: `.Cells(x, 1)`, .`Cells(x, 2),` etc., not `.Cell`. Also, your comparison of `Cells(x, 1)` to `Range($C$2:$c$92")` is problematic. Maybe use `Range.Find` or `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
        Sheet2.Range("F25") = Sheets("Resolution").Cells(x, 1)
        Sheet2.Range("G25") = Sheets("Resolution").Cells(x, 2)
        Sheet2.Range("H25") = Sheets("Resolution").Cells(x, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. Beyond the *Cell* vs. *Cell**s*** issue, there is the direct comparison of a single cell to multiple cells in a range as well as an unused offset count.

A *With ... End With* block could reduce the code and recurring worksheet reference calls.

```
Option Explicit

Sub searchdata()

    Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long, count As Long

    WITH Sheets("Resolution")

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        count = 0

        For x = 2 To lastrow
            'the next line will continue if the value in Resolution
            'is found within Sheet2.Range("$C2:$c92")
            If NOT ISERROR(APPLICATION.MATCH(.Cells(x, 1), Sheet2.Range("$C2:$c92"), 0)) Then
                Sheet2.Range("F25").OFFSET(count, 0) = .CellS(x, 1)
                Sheet2.Range("G25").OFFSET(count, 0) = .CellS(x, 2)
                Sheet2.Range("H25").OFFSET(count, 0) = .CellS(x, 3)
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next x

    END WITH

end sub
```

Comment: It didn't wok for me. I tried the code though with changes shown.